# indicate a "mode" that is not changeable by the user

Tags: radio-buttons, disable

My deployment app has 2 modes: *Local* and *Remote*.  The mode used depends on where the app is being launched.  Once the app has been launched the user can't change the mode.  However I still want to indicate the mode because the mode affects how the app acts and I want to make that visible.

Currently I am using a pair of disabled radio buttons, with whichever mode is active selected.  This works visually but I get the feeling that it's not ideal.  I don't want to just use a text label such as **Deployment Mode: Remote** because that won't make it clear what the other possible mode is.

Here is what it looks like:

[image: disabled radio buttons]

**EDIT:** This is a Windows Forms app, not a web app

Comment: if the user cannot change it, why is the mode important? what knowledge does the user gain from knowing that there is a second mode? that should clarify how much the element should be stressed (or not stressed).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the radio buttons are a bad idea per se, but it's an explanation that itself raises new questions: if there are other modes, why can't I switch to them? It would be best to support this (or a simple label) with an explanation of the current mode and what it takes to be able to switch to the other mode.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxdHj8.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You could give the information required whilst also adding value by indicating the last time the modes were used. For example:

[image]

Comment: This gave me an idea... I didn't realize it was possible to do "disabled labels"

Answer (score 1):

I would not use radio buttons unless the user can interact with it.

You can use a simple **label or hyperlink** (explaining what the modes are) instead.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frLkE3.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

You can have a overlay or a modal window pop-up when you click on the mode to explain what it is.

Comment: What should the hyperlink do?

Comment: Anyway, hyperlinks would not work... it is a Windows Forms app not a web app

Comment: @JoelFan Hyperlinks link pages across an application as well, it is not just limited to web app. Anyways, edited the mockup to show what it does.

Answer (score 1):

@Roger Attrill's answer gave me the idea to try *disabled labels*, which I handn't thought of before.

[image: disabled label]

Comment: I would support disabled labels, with a hoverover popover explaining why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The status bar is often used for displaying the state, edit mode, or otherwise non-editable non-critical information, without cluttering the main pane.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fckbKO.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

If however the information is crucial because the functionality becomes crippled / very different then it's always good to alert the user and make sure they acknowledge that particular detail upfront (you can still use a status bar or a label as a reminder later on)

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLF6S0.png)</sup>

reference:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status_bar

Comment: Hi @dnozay, welcome to UX.se! Can you explain why you think showing it in the status bar is a better alternative than the other answers? Currently, you answer seems incomplete.

Comment: @rk, I actually don't know if it is better, it all depends on how much weight that information should have.